# Is there a way to write jQuery plugins in ES6 and UMD using rollup

Tags: jquery, plugins, ecmascript-6, rollup

I am trying to figure out how to write a jQuery plugin in UMD format using rollup. So far I haven't been able to find a solution.

What I want to achieve is that I should be able to hook up methods to jquery which is `required` or `imported` as an ES6 module, as well as, keep standalone methods as well.

For example:

I should be able to do the following:

```js
import { myMethod } from 'myPlugin';
myMethod({ ... });
```

and

```js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'myPlugin';

$.myMethod({ ... });
```

I am hoping that the problem statement is clear.